Is this solution to an SAT problem provided by College Board correct?
I don't think a line parallel to the bases of a trapezoid necessarily results in two figures that are similar. Thanks for your help! 

This is Thales's Theorem

@vallev In the figure shown, Thales theorem would mean FE / ED = AB / BC, but that does not, in my view, imply that the two quadrilaterals inside the trapezoid are similar. I am wondering if the first line of the solution given is correct.

They need not be similar. EG If $A=F$, then clearly they are not similar. $\quad$ The rest of the logic works (with Thales Theorem)

The two quadrilaterals do not need to be similar as Calvin said, however the rest of the calculation is correct.

The correct statement should be that the angles of AFEB and BECD are congruent

It is true that two quadrilaterals inside the trapezoid are not necessarily similar (in fact, they are only similar when $AF = BE = CD$), however this is not conflicting with the fact that with three parallel lines, the two ratios ($\frac{AB}{BC}
$ & $\frac{FE}{ED}
$) stays constant (same as ratio of the distance between the two $\frac{d_1}{d_2}
$).
In the two examples I drew below, it is apparent that $\frac{AB}{BC}
$ stays at 1 even when the quadrilateral $ABEF$ is overlapping with itself. So, to answer your question, the two are indeed not similar quadrilaterals, but the rest of the logic stands and the answer is correct.


